# Add Custom Wishlist button in PDP Page in PWA Venia setup

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa

We are using PWA Venia Theme. We need to add custom Wishlist button below BUY NOW button in PDP Page. Here is src/components/ProductFulldetail - ProductfullDetail.js  : https://pastebin.com/jDa9t7iq

i am using this code , but this is not displaying the button.

```
<div className="flex pb-[2rem] justify-center mt-10">
                {crossSellProducts && crossSellProducts.length > 0 && (
                    <div className="w-[100%] bg-[#F7F2EC] rounded-lg">
                        <CompleteLook
                            wishlistButtonProps={wishlistButtonProps}
                            productDetails={productDetails}
                            products={crossSellProducts}
                        />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find the {cartActionContent} this code into your ProductfullDetail.js

and add this code below this like this

```
{cartActionContent}
<Suspense fallback={null}>
   <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
</Suspense>
```

I have found this code is two times repeated in mobile or desktop conditions so add the code two times.

like line no around 1245 and 1303 here both place you have to add this code same.

please check and let me know if there are any questions.

Thanks.